# How can I select and update text nodes in mixed content using lxml?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I need to check all words in all `text()` nodes in an XML file. I'm using the XPath `//text()` to select the text nodes and a regex to select the words. If the word exists in a set of keywords, I need to replace it with something and update the XML.

Normally setting the text of an element is done using `.text`, but `.text` on an _Element would only change the first child text node. In a [mixed content element](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-mixed-content), the other text nodes would actually be the `.tail` of it's preceding sibling.

How can I update all of the text nodes?

In the following simplified example I'm just trying to wrap matching keywords in square braces...

**Input XML**

```xml
<doc>
    <para>I think the only card she has <gotcha>is the</gotcha> Lorem card. We have so many things that we have to do
        better... and certainly ipsum is one of them. When other <gotcha>websites</gotcha> give you text, they're not
        sending the best. They're not sending you, they're <gotcha>sending words</gotcha> that have lots of problems
        and they're <gotcha>bringing</gotcha> those problems with us. They're bringing mistakes. They're bringing
        misspellings. They're typists… And some, <gotcha>I assume</gotcha>, are good words.</para>
</doc>
```

**Desired Output**

```xml
<doc>
    <para>I think [the] only card she has <gotcha>[is] [the]</gotcha> Lorem card. We have so many things that we have to do
        better... and certainly [ipsum] [is] one of them. When other <gotcha>websites</gotcha> give you text, they're not
        sending [the] [best]. They're not sending you, they're <gotcha>sending words</gotcha> that have lots of [problems]
        and they're <gotcha>bringing</gotcha> those [problems] with us. They're bringing [mistakes]. They're bringing
        misspellings. They're typists… And some, <gotcha>I assume</gotcha>, are good words.</para>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the key to this solution in the docs: [Using XPath to find text](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#using-xpath-to-find-text)

Specifically the `is_text` and `is_tail` properties of [_ElementUnicodeResult](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult-class.html).

Using these properties I can tell if I need to update the `.text` or `.tail` property of the parent [_Element](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html).

This is a little tricky understand at first because when you use `getparent()` on a text node (`_ElementUnicodeResult`) that is a tail of its preceding sibling (`.is_tail == True`), the preceding sibling is what's returned as the parent; not the actual parent.

Example...

**Python**

```py
import re
from lxml import etree

xml = """<doc>
    <para>I think the only card she has <gotcha>is the</gotcha> Lorem card. We have so many things that we have to do
        better... and certainly ipsum is one of them. When other <gotcha>websites</gotcha> give you text, they're not
        sending the best. They're not sending you, they're <gotcha>sending words</gotcha> that have lots of problems
        and they're <gotcha>bringing</gotcha> those problems with us. They're bringing mistakes. They're bringing
        misspellings. They're typists… And some, <gotcha>I assume</gotcha>, are good words.</para>
</doc>
"""


def update_text(match, word_list):
    if match in word_list:
        return f"[{match}]"
    else:
        return match


root = etree.fromstring(xml)

keywords = {"ipsum", "is", "the", "best", "problems", "mistakes"}

for text in root.xpath("//text()"):
    parent = text.getparent()
    updated_text = re.sub(r"[\w]+", lambda match: update_text(match.group(), keywords), text)
    if text.is_text:
        parent.text = updated_text
    elif text.is_tail:
        parent.tail = updated_text

etree.dump(root)
```

**Output** (dumped to console)

```xml
<doc>
    <para>I think [the] only card she has <gotcha>[is] [the]</gotcha> Lorem card. We have so many things that we have to do
        better... and certainly [ipsum] [is] one of them. When other <gotcha>websites</gotcha> give you text, they're not
        sending [the] [best]. They're not sending you, they're <gotcha>sending words</gotcha> that have lots of [problems]
        and they're <gotcha>bringing</gotcha> those [problems] with us. They're bringing [mistakes]. They're bringing
        misspellings. They're typists… And some, <gotcha>I assume</gotcha>, are good words.</para>
</doc>
```